# Compare two dates with different format

Tags: text-processing, awk, date

I have two files, each file contain a different date's format as below:

*File1:*

```
2014-NOV-0620:59:59
```

*File2:*

```
2014-12-31
```

How can I compare those two dates in awk?

Comment: Is that first value missing a space between the date and time? If so please [edit] your question to fix it

Comment: @roaima No, it is generated this way.

Comment: I usually use `strptime` somehow to convert the timestamps to epoch, then compare epochs.

Comment: (1) "Sorry I forgot to mention that only dates that need to be compared, the time is insignificant here."  So ***[edit] the question*** to fix it.  (2) What does "compare those dates" mean?  Establish which comes first?  Compute how far apart they are?

Answer (score 1):

perl is handy

```
use Time::Piece;

my $date1 = "2014-NOV-0620:59:59";
my $date2 = "2014-12-31";

my $datetime1 = Time::Piece->strptime($date1, "%Y-%b-%d%H:%M:%S");
my $datetime2 = Time::Piece->strptime($date2, "%Y-%m-%d");

if ($datetime1 < $datetime2) {
    print "$date1 is earlier than $date2\n";
}
elsif ($datetime1 > $datetime2) {
    print "$date1 is later than $date2\n";
}
else {
    print "$date1 is equal to $date2\n";
}
```

GNU awk:

```
gawk '
    function parse_date_fmt_1(date,     epoch, regex, month) {
        regex = "([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:alpha:]]{3})-([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2})"
        if (match(date, regex, m)) {
            month = index("..JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC", toupper(m[2])) / 3
            epoch = mktime(m[1] " " month " " m[3] " " m[4] " " m[5] " " m[6])
        }
        return epoch
    }

    function parse_date_fmt_2(date,     epoch, regex) {
        regex = "([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})"
        if (match(date, regex, m)) {
            epoch = mktime(m[1] " " m[2] " " m[3] " 0 0 0")
        }
        return epoch
    }

    BEGIN { 
        date1 = "2014-NOV-0620:59:59"
        print parse_date_fmt_1(date1)

        date2 = "2014-12-31"
        print parse_date_fmt_2(date2)
    }
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a specific date/time to compare with a date only is problematic. What time to assign to the date? I'll assume the first moment of the day (midnight). The general idea is to generate seconds since the unix epoch, so it's simple to compare them.

```
d2=$( date -d "2014-12-31" "+%s" )
echo $d2
1420009200

#date cmd requires day-month-year order (if month is alpha) and proper case
fixed_date=$( echo $a | awk '{a=substr($0,0,11);b=substr($0,12,19);printf("%11s %8s\n",a,b)}' | awk '{a=tolower($0);print a}' | sed 's/[[:alpha:]]/\u&/' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[- ]"};{print $3"-"$2"-"$1,$4}' )

d1=$( date -d "$fixed_date" "+%s" )
echo $d1
1415332799

#compare to confirm the time between dates
echo "($d2-$d1)/60/60/24" | bc -l
54.125...

#example - convert seconds back to a date
date -d @$d2 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2014-12-31 00:00:00
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that only dates that need to be compared, the time is insignificant here.